# access a single object in a returned collection (jquery)

Tags: jquery

Okay, if I have a html document that looks a bit like this:

```
<div class='item'> ... </div>
<div class='item'> ... </div>
<div class='item'> ... </div>
<div class='item'> ... </div>
```

I know I an iterate over them by doing

```
$('.item').each
```

But what if I already know I want to do something with the second one? Is there some sort of syntax similar to:

```
$('.item')[2]
```

which is usable as a selector? ie. I'd want to do:

```
$('.item')[2].css('display','block');
```

Possible or not? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) will restrict the jQuery set to just the one element you want:

```
$('.item').eq(2).css('display','block');
```

There is also an [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector) selector that will do the same:

```
$('.item:eq(2)').css('display','block');
```

As Andy mentions in the comments, both of these functions use *zero-based* indexing... Meaning `2` is the **third** element...

Comment: Remember that both forms of *eq()* accept a zero-based integer, so 0 is the first item, 1 is the second, etc...